# When to use new ObjectId("string-id") over ObjectId("string-id") in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

Since I want to be consistent with my code (Node.js)

When I have a query and need to search for something using the id value which is an unique object, what is the best way to preform it?

```
User.findOne({id: new ObjectId("82jf20k2k...")}...
```

OR

```
User.findOne({id: ObjectId("82jf20k2k...")}...
```

It seems wrong to create a new instance and filling the memory every time with objects.

The only reasonable time using *new ObjectId* is when data is being inserted for all other operations I would use *ObjectId*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/39215f038b6787d015bdd1525e4b9db060603350/lib/bson/objectid.js#L38):

```
/**
* Create a new ObjectID instance
*
* @class
* @param {(string|number)} id Can be a 24 byte hex string, 12 byte binary string or a Number.
* @property {number} generationTime The generation time of this ObjectId instance
* @return {ObjectID} instance of ObjectID.
*/
var ObjectID = function ObjectID(id) {
  // Duck-typing to support ObjectId from different npm packages
  if (id instanceof ObjectID) return id;
  if (!(this instanceof ObjectID)) return new ObjectID(id);

  this._bsontype = 'ObjectID';

  // more code
```

For what I see it is the same thing doing `new` or `ObjectId("82jf20k2k...")` as if it is not instance of `ObjectID` it's going to create a new instance and return it.

Comment: It is the same thing, but why would I instantiate a new objectId instead of just calling ObjectId which would return the id

Comment: @eugensunic it doesn't just return the id, it returns id if it's an instance of `ObjectId` so you are getting the object in both cases

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, it is the same, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use 2nd option i.e.

> User.findOne({id: ObjectId("82jf20k2k...")}...

you are right 1st one is creating unnecessary object in memory. **New** keyword should be used in case you want to generate ObjectID at run time.

Comment: Although agreeing with you, I don't really see where exactly is this being mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like this:

```
User.findOne({ id: "82jf20k2k..." })
```

no need for "ObjectId()" as the findOne will try to convert the string to ObjectId.

Also, if you want to search documents by Id, use findById as it is more prefered.

Reference:
[mongoose model.js from Github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js)

Comment: By looking at the source code which others have provided you are right, however running this with mongo does not work you have to provide the Id, I'm not sure about mongoose but do not want to rely on some hidden code which could or could not do an action.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `Model.findById()` instead of `Model.findOne(_id:id)`, to find document based on it's _id.

You can also find more info on [Mongoose Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById).